# Choose a random post from an asyncpraw subreddit generator object?

Tags: python, random, generator, python-asyncio, praw

(asynchronous Python stuff for a discord bot)

Using the reddit API via `asyncpraw`

I am making a call to the reddit API and returning a subreddit's ten hot posts.

`hot_posts = returned_subreddit.hot(limit=10)`

Which prints `<asyncpraw.models.listing.generator.ListingGenerator object at 0x0000021B3CC1A3A0>`

This object can be iterated through and different attributes can be used. e.g.:

```py
async for submission in hot_posts:
    print(submission.title)
    print(submission.score)
    print(submission.id)
    print(submission.url)
```

I would like to know how to choose a random submission from this generator object. The goal is for my discord bot to send a message in response to a command. The message would include a link to one of top ten hot posts on a given subreddit.

I've tried accessing it via an index e.g. `hot_posts[3]` which threw  `TypeError: 'ListingGenerator' object is not subscriptable`

Tried so far using `random` library:

`choice(hot_posts)`
Result: `TypeError: object of type 'ListingGenerator' has no len()`

`random.sample(hot_posts, k=1)`
Result: `TypeError: Population must be a sequence.  For dicts or sets, use sorted(d).`

Docs:

https://asyncpraw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/subreddit.html

https://asyncpraw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/other/listinggenerator.html#asyncpraw.models.ListingGenerator

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this, probably very imperfectly. The answer to the above question was to educate myself about generator objects, how they use `yield`, and how they are not iterable and should either be consumed until a random stop point, or consumed into a list which is then selected from at random.

```
    @commands.command()
    async def r(self, ctx, subreddit: str=""):
        async with ctx.channel.typing():
            if self.reddit:
                chosen_subreddit = REDDIT_ENABLED_MEME_SUBREDDITS[0]
                if subreddit:
                    if subreddit in REDDIT_ENABLED_MEME_SUBREDDITS:
                        chosen_subreddit = subreddit
                sub = await self.reddit.subreddit(chosen_subreddit)
                submission_list = [submission async for submission in sub.hot(limit=20) if not submission.stickied and not submission.over_18 and not submission.spoiler]
                selector = randint(0, len(submission_list) - 1)
                post = submission_list[selector]
                await ctx.send(f"{post.url}\n<https://www.reddit.com{post.permalink}>")
            else:
                await ctx.send("This is not working.")
```

Comment: dang thanks so much! The line: submission_list = [submission async for submission in sub.hot(limit=20) if not submission.stickied and not submission.over_18 and not submission.spoiler] was very much needed since I never thought async